# Let $p \in \Bbb Z$ be prime, and $a, b \in \Bbb Z$ such that $(a, b) = p$. Find the greatest common divisor of $a^2$ and $b^2$, and prove your result.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm struggling to understand where to go with this one. I know that both $a$ and $b$ can be written as multiples of primes, and that the greatest common factor between these two is given as $p$, but I don't know what to do with this information. If I square both $a$ and $b$, can I square both of their products of primes? If so, is the greatest common factor simply $p$ squared? How do I actually demonstrate that?

Comment: Yes, it is $p^2$. Write down the factorization of both a and b as $p \mul (some number)$. Square both of them and you will see that it is indeed $p^2$

Comment: It's still not clear to me why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Since $p|a$ we have $a=pa'$ and likewise $b=pb'$

Then $p^2|a^2=p^2a'^2$ and $p^2|b^2=p^2b'^2$ so $p^2$ is a common factor of the squares.

Now suppose that the prime $q$ (which may be equal to $p$) is such that $p^2q$ is a common factor of $a^2$ and $b^2$. Then $q$ is a common factor of $a'^2$ and $b'^2$.

Now note that $q|a'^2$ implies $q|a'$ (by the property of being a prime) and likewise $q|b'$ whence $pq$ is a common factor of $a=pa'$ and $b=pb'$. This is a contradiction to $(a , b) =p$, so $q$ cannot exist.

There are some bits to fill in to make this a full proof.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the prime factorizations $a = u_1p_1^{\nu_1} \cdot \dots \cdot p_n^{\nu_n}$ and $b = u_2q_1^{\eta_1} \cdot \dots \cdot q_m^{\eta_m}$, where the $u_i$ are units. Since $(a,b) =p$ we know that the only (non-unit) common factor of both of these is $p$. That means that there exists $1 \leq i \leq n$ and $1 \leq j \leq m$, such that $p_i = p = q_j$ and that the corresponding powers are equal to $1$ and that no other primes of the factorizations coincide. If you square $a$ and $b$ you multiply all the powers accuring in the factorization by $2$. Therefore you get $p^2$ as gcd, since all the other primes were no common divisors.